# Pandas write_frame deletes sqlite table

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

When attempting to overwrite a sqlite table with the contents of a Pandas `dataframe`, Pandas `DROP`s the table, but doesn't recreate it before attempting the `INSERT`.

Here's a minimum working example:

```
import sqlite3 as sq
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as pd_sql

d = pd.DataFrame({'year':[2008,2008,2008,2008,2009,2009,2009,2009], 
                  'flavour':['strawberry','strawberry','banana','banana',
                  'strawberry','strawberry','banana','banana'],
                  'day':['sat','sun','sat','sun','sat','sun','sat','sun'],
                  'sales':[10,12,22,23,11,13,23,24]})

# Connect to the database (create if necessary)                  
conn = sq.connect('mydb')

# Create the table 'mytable' if necessary
if not pd_sql.table_exists('mytable', conn, 'sqlite'):
    pd_sql.write_frame(d, 'mytable', conn)

# Change some data    
d['sales'][d.sales==24] = 25

# Confirm the table exists
print "Table 'mytable' exists:"
print pd_sql.table_exists('mytable', conn, 'sqlite')

# Get some data from the table
cur = pd_sql.execute("SELECT DISTINCT flavour FROM mytable", conn)
print "Here's the data to prove the table exists:"
print cur.fetchall()

try:
    print "Attempting write_frame..."
    pd_sql.write_frame(d, 'mytable', conn, if_exists='replace')
except sq.OperationalError as e:
    print "sq.OperationalError is: " + str(e)
    print pd_sql.table_exists('mytable', conn, 'sqlite')
    conn.close()
```

Running this script results in the following output:

```
Table 'mytable' exists:
True
Here's the data to prove the table exists:
[(u'banana',), (u'strawberry',)]
Attempting write_frame...
sq.OperationalError is: no such table: mytable
Table 'mytable' exists after write_frame:
False
```

This looks like a bug in Pandas. Is anyone able to confirm this?

Thanks as always,
Rob

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report (so should be posted [on github as an issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)).

Comment: @AndyHayden is this the same? https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2971

Comment: @Jeff looks like it is, don't think it's merged, will address after SQLAlchemy stuff is done.

Comment: Sorry gents, didn't believe I could have found an actual bug! I'll post the workaround I've been using as an 'answer' to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments to the original post, this has been confirmed to be a known bug in Pandas.

This workaround seems ok to me:

```
pd_sql.uquery("DELETE FROM mytable", conn)
pd_sql.write_frame(d, 'mytable', conn, if_exists='append')
```